# Failed to resolve: com.github.KwabenBerko:News-API-Java:1.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

***CODE***

android {
compileSdk 31

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.newsapi"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.KwabenBerko:News-API-Java:1.0.0'
```

}

***PROBLEM***
I am using the NewsApi, which I have Implemented in the build.gradle(module level) of my project. But it is throwing ---> Failed to resolve: com.github.KwabenBerko:News-API-Java:1.0.0

Comment: Have you added  ' maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }'   the JitPack repository to your root build.gradle file.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }